# merge conflict after ammending message. can't pull or push

Tags: git, github, merge-conflict-resolution

I commited but realized there was a mistake in the message. I ran

`git commit --amend -o -m "blah blah"`

I then deleted the file (on purpose) and then did

```
git add .
git commit -m "blah blah"
git push origin master
```

and got the error

! [rejected]        master -> master (non-fast-forward)

I tried to fix it with `git pull origin master` and got

`CONFLICT (modify/delete): MyFile.java deleted in HEAD and modified in ad0c109`

what is going on and how do I fix it? I just want there to be a history that I deleted the file. I intend to create a new one with the same name.

**Update:**
I ran `git push -f origin master` and it worked. Now `git status` gives

> On branch master All conflicts fixed but you are still merging.   (use
>   "git commit" to conclude merge)

I ran `git commit` and got

> E325: ATTENTION Found a swap file by the name
>   "C:/Users/Dev3/Documents/NetBeansProjects/OctRecProj/src/OctRecProj/.git/.COMMIT_EDITMSG.swp"
>             owned by: Dev3   dated: Sun May 22 03:27:31 2016
>            file name: ~Dev3/Documents/NetBeansProjects/OctRecProj/src/OctRecProj/.git/COMMIT_EDITMSG
>             modified: YES
>            user name: Dev3   host name: Desktop-D
>           process ID: 2844 While opening file "C:/Users/Dev3/Documents/NetBeansProjects/OctRecProj/
>   src/OctRecProj/.git/COMMIT_EDITMSG"
>                dated: Thu Oct 13 03:22:34 2016
>         NEWER than swap file!
>
> (1) Another program may be editing the same file.  If this is the
>   case,
>       be careful not to end up with two different instances of the same
>       file when making changes.  Quit, or continue with caution. (2) An edit session for this file crashed.
>       If this is the case, use ":recover" or "vim -r C:/Users/Dev3/Documents/NetBe
>   ansProjects/OctRecProj/src/OctRecProj/.git/COMMIT_EDITMSG"
>       to recover the changes (see ":help recovery").
>       If you did this already, delete the swap file "C:/Users/Dev3/Documents/NetBe
>   ansProjects/OctRecProj/src/OctRecProj/.git/.COMMIT_EDITMSG.swp"
>   -- More --

Comment: what does git status give you after you have tried to pull?

Comment: @Gernot `You have unmerged paths.` and refers to the file I deleted.

Comment: The `.swp` file messages suggest you're using vim and still have a vim running on those files (perhaps in another window).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to resolve merge conflicts in Git?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/161813/how-to-resolve-merge-conflicts-in-git)

Answer (score 5):

Let's make a few notes, then draw some commit graphs, since `git merge`'s actions depend critically on both the commit graph *and* the trees attached to the three "interesting" commits.

1. `git commit --amend` does not modify a commit (because this is impossible).  Instead, it makes a new commit and shoves the old one aside to make room for the new one, instead of doing the usual "add new one on the end".
2. `git commit -o` (or `--only`) omits the current index (staging area), making a temporary index instead, starting from the previous commit.  That's a reasonable enough thing to do when amending, although if you have not staged anything, this has no effect.  So this "amended" (really, copied) commit will have the same *tree* as the original commit, even if you had staged something.  (This only matters for note 3.)
3. Finally, the subsequent `git commit` (after removing a file and staging the removal) will make a new commit with the file removed, plus anything *else* you already had staged (as noted in note 2).

Now, we don't know whether the commit you're amending here is a merge commit itself, but let's just assume it isn't.  (If it is, the picture gets more complicated, but the *result* is the same.)  We also don't know for sure, but can reasonably assume, that the commit you're amending was already pushed—since that's precisely what will cause this problem.  So, we can draw the graphs like this.

First, we draw the "before" situation: before you amended anything.  That graph is pretty straightforward:

```
...--o--*--A   <-- master, origin/master
```

That is, your branch `master` points to commit `A` (the one we're about to "amend"), and `origin/master`—your copy of `master` as seen in the other Git repository, over on the machine `origin`—also points to commit `A`.  Commit `*` is the commit just before `A`; this one will be important later.  There are additional earlier commits as well.

Now let's draw the graph *after* amending, but before making any new commits:

```
          A    <-- origin/master
         /
...--o--*
         \
          A'   <-- master
```

Commit `A'` is the amended commit, with slightly different message.  It has the same *tree* as commit `A`—the same source code—but a different message, and therefore a different SHA-1 ID.

Let's add on the commit that deletes the file, and call this `D` for `D`elete:

```
          A      <-- origin/master
         /
...--o--*
         \
          A'-D   <-- master
```

You now try to `git push origin master` and get an error.  The error is because, on `origin`, *their* `master` points to commit `A`, or perhaps even some commit(s) after `A` that you do not have.<sup>1</sup>  Let's just proceed with the theory that `origin` is not a super-active repository gaining ten new commits per second or whatever, though, and hope that it's just `A`. :-)

What their Git, over on `origin`, is complaining about is that if they let you do this `git push`, they will "lose" commit `A`.  Your Git is asking their Git to set *their* `master` to point to your commit `D` (after, of course, handing over your `A'` and your `D`).  If they do that, they will no longer have a name pointing to commit `A`: commit `A` will be forgotten.

Of course, this is precisely what you did to your own repository when you amended `A`.  You told your Git: "forget about `A`, shove it off to one side where the only name for it is `origin/master`, and give me an `A'` copy with a different message."

OK, so far so good, except that the push failed.  So you ran `git pull origin master`.

---

<sup>1</sup>It's not possible to tell precisely what they had then, although you *can* see, now, what you have now, which will match up with what they had right when you ran `git pull`.  Of course your `git pull` was at least several whole seconds ago, and who knows how much has changed in that time!  Seriously, there's a synchronization issue because whatever you're doing in your Git, someone else may be doing other things in other Gits right now.  How much of a problem this is for you depends on just how active `origin` is.

---

#### `git pull` is *not* the opposite of `git push`

In fact, there is no exact opposite for `git push`.  The closest thing is `git fetch`, which tells your Git to call up their Git, same as with a push, but instead of sending them *your* commits and asking *them* to move *their* branches, you get *their* commits, and you have your Git move your "remote-tracking branches": your `origin/master`.

What `git pull` does is first run `git fetch`, and then run `git merge`.

#### `git fetch`

The first part of `git pull origin master` is that Git runs `git fetch origin master`.

This `fetch` step called up their Git and brought over their new commits.  We're assuming there were none: that their `master` still points to their `A`, which is also your `A`.  So your Git updated your `origin/master` to keep pointing to your `A` (not much of an update: nothing changed):

```
          A      <-- origin/master
         /
...--o--*
         \
          A'-D   <-- master
```

(If they did in fact have some commits—let's call them `B` and `C`—then your Git obtained these commits and updated your `origin/master`:

```
          A--B--C   <-- origin/master
         /
...--o--*
         \
          A'-D   <-- master
```

but probably there were no such commits.  Let's proceed without them.)

#### `git merge`

The second part of `git pull origin master` is to run `git merge`, with some extra arguments that are too complicated to reproduce exactly, but more or less amount to `origin/master`.<sup>2</sup>  Let's just pretend it really is `git merge origin/master`, since that's a little easier to work with.

What `git merge` does is to first find the *merge base*, which is the first commit that is *the same* between your current branch—that's your `master`—and the commit you tell it to merge in.  The commit you (or `git pull`, really) are telling your Git to merge in is the tip of `origin/master`, i.e., commit `A`.

So now we go back to that graph we've been drawing and find the merge base.  That's commit `*`.  We also find the tip of `origin/master`, i.e., commit `A`, and the tip of our current branch: commit `D`.

Next, we make (or Git makes) two `git diff` listings:

```
git diff <id-of-*> <id-of-A>   # "what they changed"
git diff <id-of-*> <id-of-D>   # "what we changed"
```

Presumably, between commit `*` and commit `A`, "they" (whoever they were, maybe us) changed the file you deleted in `D`.

Meanwhile, between commit `*` and commit `D`, "we" deleted the file.  Note that Git doesn't even *look* at commit `A'` here: all it does is compare `*` and `D`.  It doesn't matter that we changed the file in the same way between `*` and `A'`, it only matters that we deleted the file in the overall change.

**This is the source of the merge conflict.**  Between "what they did" and "what we did", Git does not know whether to keep the *change* to the file, or keep the *deletion* of the file.

If you wish to make the merge—you probably don't—you can resolve this by running `git rm <file>` and then `git commit` to commit the merge.  The result will be a new merge commit:

```
          A    <-- origin/master
         / \
...--o--*   \__
         \     \
          A'-D--M   <-- master
```

The tree for the new merge will match that for commit `D`, but now you will have both the original commit `A` *and* the amended copy (with same tree but different commit message) in your history.

You will be able to push this to `origin`, because now if you send them commit `M` and ask them to set their `master` to point to `M`, they won't lose commit `A`.

---

<sup>2</sup>The difference mainly shows up in the default merge commit message, which says, approximately, "merge the branch named master from the remote named origin" rather than "merge our own remote-tracking branch origin/master".  Also, if you have an ancient version of Git, predating 1.8.4, there are a few additional technical gotchas that prevent `origin/master` from working right here.  Hopefully you're not stuck with Git version 1.7.x.

---

#### What to do about this mess

First, you can abort your in-progress merge:

```
git merge --abort
```

Now you're back to the original:

```
          A      <-- origin/master
         /
...--o--*
         \
          A'-D   <-- master
```

in your repository.

The big problem here is that they, whoever they are, over on `origin`, have commit `A`.  You may be able to use a force-push to get them to ditch it:

```
git push --force origin master
```

This tells their Git "go ahead and lose commit `A`, just set your `master` to `D`.  The drawback is that if they've acquired some commit(s) `B` and/or `C` now, you will also lose those commits.  Also, if *anyone else* has acquired a copy of commit `A`, those *other* users have to do something to recover from your resetting `origin` to abandon `A` in favor of `A'`.

You can use `--force-with-lease` to tell them, in effect, "I believe your `master` points to commit `A`; if so, make your `master` point to `D` instead."  (This requires that both your Git and their Git be new enough to have the `--force-with-lease` option.)

Or, you can abandon your idea of modifying the commit message.  Just give in and transplant your commit `D` so that it comes after `A`, instead of after `A'`.  Give up your modified `A'` entirely, giving you this graph:

```
          A      <-- origin/master
         / \
...--o--*   D'   <-- master
         \
          A'-D   [abandoned]
```

You can now push this because your new copy `D'` of your original `D` simply adds on to their existing commit `A`.  If, after doing this, we forget about the abandoned commits entirely and draw this more nicely, we get:

```
...--o--*--A--D   <-- master, origin
```

which is a nice straight history, and is what you were hoping for.

#### Summary

Your three options, after using `git merge --abort` to escape the in-progress merge, are:

1. force push;
2. force-with-lease;
3. give up on the amend: cherry-pick `D` into `D'`, or repeat your deletion to create `D'`, after resetting your own `master` to point the same place as `origin/master`.

(If `origin` is private enough, option 1 is safe and easy.  [Also, pushing while you're in the in-progress merge is largely harmless since push only pushes completed commits.])

Comment: I did `git push -f origin master` but it still complains "you are still merging" (see update on main question for full details)

Comment: You haven't yet done the `git merge --abort` to terminate the conflicted merge.  (I'll put the merge abort into the summary too)

Comment: I have the same complaint after each problem like this: why is it so difficult? Isn't the point of git to make version control easier. I just wanted to add something to a message.

Comment: Can there be multiple `commits` in one `push`? I usually do a `push` right after each `commit` so maybe this is the problem. Could you do *work* `commit -m "msg 1"` *work* `-commit -m "msg 2"` *work* `commit -m "msg 2"; push` and it would save all 3 messages?

Comment: Yes!  The `push` takes (from your side) a commit ID and (for their side) a branch name (or other reference). Your Git then sends whatever objects—commits and the files that go with them—that you have, that they don't, and last, asks them to set their name to your just-delivered commit ID. If you `git push origin master` your Git uses your `master`'s commit ID and the name `master` (though this glosses over `push.default` and a lot of other configurable settings). If you're 3 commits ahead, that pushes all 3 in one go, and then sets their `master` to the tip-most.

Comment: As for why it's so difficult: Git sometimes seems like a kit car that you have to build from individual spark plugs, bolts, cylinder heads, pistons, rings, steering linkages, tires, fenders, and so on. :-) It lets you control *everything*, even if that's not what you actually *want*....

Answer (score 1):

I assume that this is what happened:

1. You changed MyFile.java and committed the change as commit *A*.
2. You pushed your change, so the remote repository contains commit *A*.
3. You amended the commit and thus created commit *B* (which is in fact a new commit with the same changes as *A* had).
4. You deleted the file and committed that change creating commit *C*.

To check if this is the situation you are in, you could do `git log` and `git log origin/{branchname}` (assuming that your remote repo is called origin and you replace {branchname} with the name of the branch you push to). The remote branch should contain the branch with the old message, while the local branch contains the new message.

Now locally you have commits *B* and *C* while the remote repository contains the commit *A*. When you do `git pull`, git tries to fetch the commit *A* from the remote repository. This commit contains a change to the file MyFile.java. When git tries to apply that change to your local repository, it recognizes that that file has been deleted in the meantime.

A little more explanation:
git recognizes commits based on their hashes. The hash is calculated based on many information, amongst them are the diff done by that commit, the previous commit, the message and also the time of the commit. Thus if you amend the commit, the hash changes. In the future git does recognize the commit before and after the change as different commits.

You have multiple ways to handle that issue. As you commented in the meantime that the repo is not shared but only you are working with it, option 2 is most probably the preferred one.

1. Solve the merge commit by deciding to delete the file. This however will lead to both commits *A* and *B* existing in your history, which contain the same changes but different messages.
2. Force push your changes with `git push -f`. This will remove commit *A* from the remote repository and push your commits *B* and *C*. This will lead to problems, if anyone else has already fetched your changes from the remote repository, as they will get the same problems you got before.
3. Do not amend the commit and keep it in the old state. To get that state back, you can first store the commit hash of the commit deleting MyFile.java anywhere to use it later on. Than do a `git reset --hard A` (attention: if you have any open changes left, this will remove those, so stash them before) and afterwards `git cherry-pick C` where *C* is the hash of the commit deleting the file. If you have done more commits than that one, proceed for them accordingly (remembering their hashes and picking them later on).

Comment: What should I have done differently to avoid this situation aka what did I do wrong? Was it because I didn't `git push` after amending? The new message did appear on github...

Comment: You could have avoided it only by not pushing before amending the commit. If you had pulled before deleting the file you probably wouldn't have gotten any merge conflict, however the problem of the duplicate commit would still exist.

Comment: It still gives an error when I do `git status` please see update in main question

Answer (score 0):

Did you push after change the commit message?
After git ammend, push that change. Then run the commands to delete the file.
P.S - I didnt get this issue when I followed the steps you have mentioned

Comment: No I did not push after the amend, I didn't know I needed to.

Comment: You don't need to, I tried the same steps as you, but didn't get any error, but worth trying push first.

Comment: I always get random merge conflict errors and I don't know why

Comment: Most of the conflicts can be avoided if, once you are about to commit your change in a shared repo, stash your code, take a pull, apply stash, resolve conflicts if any, commit and push.

Comment: The repo isn't even shared, it's just me

Comment: to resolve this issue, try - git reset --soft origin/master. This should bring you local in sync with remote with your local changes applied on top. If you see conflicts, try resolving and commit/push

Answer (score 0):

If you didn't push the branch before amending, it means that someone else did some changes on the remote master branch and it's not related the amend of the commit.

When you did a pull, git fetched the remote modifications of the branch and then tried to merge it in your local branch, this failed cause the file you deleted was modified in the other commits, so I guess you need to synchronize with the other person to see why they changed this file.

You need to resolve this conflict manually.

Another option is to rebase your local branch master on the remote branch, you'll still have the conflict but you'll avoid having a merge commit in your history.

Comment: No one else did any changes. I'm the only one working on the project. Also I saw my amended message on github so I don't think it needed a `git push` after.